# CloudKit Not Fetching Newly Inserted Records

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I am using CloudKit to insert data into the database. The initial fetch works fine but when I add a new record and try to fetch all records again, it ignores the last inserted record. If I run the app again, my newly created record shows up correctly. So, the question is why I am not able to get all the records after inserting a brand new record.

```
func saveItem(title: String, price: Decimal) {
        
        let record = CKRecord(recordType: RecordType.itemListing.rawValue)
        let itemListing = ItemListing(title: title, price: price)
        record.setValuesForKeys(itemListing.toDictionary())
        
        self.database.save(record) { newRecord, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                // get all items from CloudKit
                self.populateItems()
            }
        }
    }


 func populateItems() {
        
        var items: [ItemListing] = []
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: RecordType.itemListing.rawValue, predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
       
        database.fetch(withQuery: query) { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let result):
                    print(result.matchResults)
                     result.matchResults.compactMap { $0.1 }
                     .forEach {
                         switch $0 {
                             case .success(let record):
                                 
                                 if let itemListing = ItemListing.fromRecord(record) {
                                     items.append(itemListing)
                                 }
                                 
                             case .failure(let error):
                                 print(error)
                         }
                         
                     }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.items = items.map(ItemViewModel.init)
                    }
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Conceptually you should not do like that. You store new data in your model and and submit the cloudkit update for persistence only. If you handle the error you will be able to restart the update or do appropriate task in your code to take the problem into account. I am not sure it us a good idea to have cloudkit calls inside cloudkit completion handler. You may run in race conditions between the different queues/threads. Did you tried using await/async .

Comment: Agree with Ptit. Put a closure on the insert, call the completion and then reload after the first call complete..